# How to integrate facebook login button in my rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

What is the easiest and reliable way to add facebook login button to my rails 3 app?

I Currently have a `User` model with `email` and `password_hash` and `password_salt`

Are there any good gems that make this easy in rails3?

Are my only options OmniAuth and Devise?  I am currently using authenticating from scratch method from railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

OmniAuth is the easiest and fastest choice, in my experience. Devise is great but much more heavyweight if all you're planning to do is Facebook OAuth.